# Why does JavaScript split() produce different output with different variable names?

Tags: javascript

Following is some codes and output from the Chrome Developers' Console

**Case 1:**

```
var myarr = document.location.hostname.split(".");    //typed
undefined                                             //output
myarr[0]                                              //typed
"ptamz"                                               //output: ONE
```

**Case 2:**

```
var name = document.location.hostname.split(".");     //typed
undefined                                             //output
name[0]                                               //typed
"p"                                                   //output: TWO
```

Why are the two outputs (commented Output: ONE, and Output: TWO) different?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Isn't `name` a reserved term? maybe that's why.

Comment: The two undefined's are expected since the dev console outputs whatever the expression evaluates to (you probably know that, but just figured I'd throw it out there).  The name[0] and myarr[0]...  Must be as James' answer says.

Comment: Same as [Using the variable “name” doesn't work with a JS object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/1529630). One should be closed as duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`name` is a property of `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.name). It appears that when you try to set that property to an array, the keys are joined with a comma (the result of calling [`toString` on an array](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2)). So you are actually setting the `window.name` property to the concatenation of each element of `document.location.hostname.split(".")`, separated by commas.

Here's a screenshot from my Chrome console demonstrating what happens:

[image]

The reason `name[0]` then results in `p` is that you can access the characters of strings using square brackets:

```
name = "hello,world";
console.log(name[0]); //"h"
```

**Edit**

As others have mentioned, this will only be the case in the global scope. You are free to declare a variable named `name` inside a descendant scope. Although, obviously, omitting the `var` keyword in this case would still result in you accessing `window.name`:

```
function example() {
    var name = ["hello", "world"];
    console.log(name); //["hello", "world"]
}
```

Comment: True.  If you try the line `var name = document.location.hostname.split(".");` inside a function, it works as expected, since that var has narrower scope than the global object, and so takes precedence.  Chrome refuses to define a new 'name' variable if it’s already defined on the `window` object, so anything you assign to it will be converted to string.

Answer (score 4):

James is right: because `name` is a string property of `window`, if you're executing this code in the global scope you're set *that* property not your variable. So, if you set an array, it set to `window.name` the string version of that array (basically, `array.toString()` that is the same of `array.join()`).

Because it's a string – and not an array – using the square notation let you access to the single character based on a specific index. So:

```
var str = "ptamz";
str[0] // "p"
str[1] // "t"
```

It's equivalent to:

```
var str = "ptamz";
str.charAt(0) // "p"
str.charAt(1) // "t"
```

Answer (score 1):

name in global scope is an empty string, so in the latter case you get the array returned by split transformed into a string "www,hostname,com". So name[0] gets you the first letter only.