# Using the variable "name" doesn't work with a JS object

Tags: javascript, object, window-object

The behaviour can be seen in this little snippet (execute it as a global script):

```
var name = {};
name.FirstName = 'Tom';
alert(name.FirstName);
```

The alert yields `undefined` in Chrome but works in IE and Firefox. I also get a weird value when I do

```
alert(name);
```

Comment: `language` attribute is deprecated, use only the `type` attribute. It's also better to use `console.log` instead of the `alert` and use the Chrome Dev. Tools (or FireBug) to read them. And finaly you need to have a doctype on line 1 of your code, a doctype is: `<!doctype html>`

Comment: AFAIK it's more common to use the `var name = {}` syntax too.

Comment: It was just typo ... I entered 'Object' not object. it still throws error in chrome. try the new code in chrome.

Comment: name is a special global variable in browsers, you can't alter it too much...

Comment: @dandavis but its not reserved keyword, and only that name variable behaves odd.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a reserved keyword. There are a bunch of special variables like that; for example, assigning to `location` will navigate to a new page.

Comment: reserved or not window.name is assuredly very special. if you set name and go to a different domain, name remains. the way that's wired forces the name property to appear as a normal string, and it cannot be redefined to a different type, just like window.location for example.

Comment: window.name is a special global variable in browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name it assumes the type is a string. If you use typeof to check nString, it is an object. You can run it in a nodejs console and the results is correct then. So it is not a javascript problem.

Comment: Yeah, thanks dandavis, i just came to know that there are other varaibles that are not reserved and yet assumed to behave like reserved.

Comment: @ChrisLi—actually, it is a JavaScript™ "problem", i.e. it's a feature of the *window* host object as implemented in browsers per Mozilla and W3C specifications, it's not part of ECMAScript.

Comment: @RobG yes, cause ECMAScript is core thing so when it comes to client side in browsers it has window global object and it has these special properties.

Comment: Same as [Why does JavaScript split() produce different output with different variable names?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9801214/1529630). One should be closed as duplicate of the other.

Comment: same thing happens with "status".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.name) has a special purpose, and is supposed to be a string. Chrome seems to explicitly cast it to a string, so `var name = {};` actually ends up giving the global variable `name` (i.e. `window.name`) a value of `"[object Object]"`. Since it's a primitive, properties (`name.FirstName`) won't "stick."

To get around this issue, don't use `name` as a global variable.

Comment: Good catch... I didn't pay attention to the variable name at all.

Comment: @FelixKling I almost treat `name` like a reserved word, since some hosts give functions a `name` property also (I've been bitten by that before), closure won't minify it, etc.

Comment: Yeah, there have been a couple of questions with that problem as far as I can remember...

Comment: fyi, the link is broken

Answer (score 16):

Your `name` variable is actually `window.name`, because top-level variables declared with `var` are attached to the global object.

The HTML5 spec [requires that `window.name` is a `DOMString`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#the-window-object). This means that the value of `window.name` can [only be a sequence of characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-DOMString), not an object.

In Chrome, an attempt to use `window.name` to store anything except a primitive string will coerce the value to a primitive string. For example:

```
window.name = {};
window.name === "[object Object]"; // true
```

You can avoid this problem by using a `name` variable that is not in the top-level scope:

```
(function() {
    var name = {};
    // this `name` is not `window.name`
    // because we're not in the top-level scope

    console.log(name);
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

With ES6+, you could write your code as `let name` or `const name`. This won't assign it or try to override `window.name`. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object).

```js
let name = {};
name.FirstName = 'Tom';
alert(name.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.name` is used to set the name of the window, and since the window name can only be a string, anything you set to `window.name` is converted to a string. And strings, as primitive values, cannot have properties. The solution is to use a different variable name or a different scope.

Alternatively, you can use `window.name` as you like if you have this code first. I don't recommend this at all, but, just as a proof of concept:

```
(function () {
    var _name;
    window.__defineGetter__('name', function () {
        return _name;
    });
    window.__defineSetter__('name', function (v) {
        _name = v;
    });
})();
```

Additionally, you should use `{}` in place of `new Object`. Besides being more concise, it is also more efficient and more explicit.

Comment: Or just `delete name;`

Comment: Note that [`__defineGetter__`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) and [`__defineSetter__`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineSetter__) are both deprecated. Use [`defineProperty`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead.