# Prevent browser from remembering JS variable after page refresh

Tags: javascript, browser, scope, global-variables

I've looked at several questions asking how to remember the variable, but I'm having  the opposite problem which is surprising to me.

My main.js file will have this:

```
console.log(name);
```

and I get nothing. If I try to log it in the console it returns undefined, that is expected,

now I create the variable like this:

```
var name = "Sandy"; //global variable
console.log(name); //returns "Sandy" which is also expected.
```

But now the unexpected happens. I remove the variable so we're back to this, and then I refresh the page:

```
console.log(name); //This returns "Sandy" still...
```

How is this happening and why? I thought it was cookies, so I tried it in incognito mode (Maybe I misunderstand incognito?) But it works exactly the same.

In order to make the variable go away I have to close down the browser and open up a new window.

After reading briefly about LocalStorage, cookies, and incognito, it sounds like cookies are the problem, but wouldn't I have to create the cookie manually?

It seems like the browsers should be forgetting the variables unless I explicitly set the variable to a cookie.

Comment: By declaring `name` in global space you are overwriting the [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property which is presistent across page changes of the same domain. You would get the same results by doing `window.name="Sandy"`

Comment: So global variables are persistent across page changes by default? I would accept this as an answer but it's a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var name and window.name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064897/var-name-and-window-name)

Comment: No, just special properties like `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring a global variable called `name` you are **overwriting** a `window.name` property, which doesn't reset on page refresh.

`window` is a built-in object, specific to each opened tab in a web browser and represents a containing document. You can read more about the `window` object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and more about its `name` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

You can also check what happens during execution of your code by logging `window.name` before and after you define your variable.

It's best to **avoid using `name` as a variable in JavaScript code that runs in a browser**. Set your variable to something else (that is not a reserved word or a propery name of a built-in object) and your code will work.