# Global variable created by function invocation holds empty string by default,should be undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

If a variable is declared but not initialized , it will print undefined in the console.But in this particular case if i `console.log(this.name)` inside Person function it should create a global variable called `name` whenever i invoke the function .But the global variable must be undefined, instead it is holding a empty string .I even checked the window object .It has a property called name which holds empty string.Why it is behaving this way ?

```js
function Person(){
     
        console.log(this.name)
    
    } 
    
    Person() // should prints undefined ,but prints empty string
```

[image]

Comment: _“if i console.log(this.name) inside Person function it should create a global variable called name whenever i invoke the function”_ - and what exactly makes you think that …?

Comment: in Firefox and nodejs the result is `undefined`

Comment: global variables are property of window object , aren't they?

Comment: In the code snippet I added it's a GUID.

Comment: Do you run this on a platform like `jsbin.com`?

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064897/var-name-and-window-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code doesn't *create* any global variable (other than `Person`, which is a kind of variable), it just tries to *use* one. But if you run it in a browser in the default loose mode, you see a string because browsers have a predefined `name` global: It's the [name of the window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) in which the code is running. (If you ran it in strict mode, you'd get an error because `this` would be `undefined` during the call.)

If you run that *not* on a browser, or with a different name (one that isn't already a global), you'll see `undefined`.

Comment: Say i have used username instead of name.How come it doesn't get attached to window object? can you explain?

Comment: @AL-zami: Because you're just *reading* the value of it. Reading the value of a non-existant property doesn't create the property, it just yields `undefined`. *Assigning* to a non-existant property creates the property.

Comment: thanx, so if i assign a value to it like this.username = "donald duck" , then i will be creating a global variable ?

Comment: @AL-zami: Yes. Of course, it's best to avoid global variables... :-)

Answer (score 0):

There *already* exists a property `name` on the global object (`window` in the browser) which is an empty string, otherwise the value would certainly be `undefined`.