# Why is this difference between `var` and `let` in firefox web console but not in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, web-console

In node.js

```
> var name = 12; 
> console.log(typeof name);
number
```

in Firefox's web console

```
var name = 12; 
console.log(typeof name);
string 

let name2 = 12; 
console.log(typeof name2);
number
```

Why is the difference between `var` and `let` in Firefox?

Why is no such difference in node.js?

Comment: Because if Firefox, `name` is `window.name` not the variable you've just created.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064897/var-name-and-window-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an inbuilt property on `window` called `name`:

```js
console.log(name);
```

So your code will look for that, not the `name` you create.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `typeof name` not number but string?

Comment: Because `window.name` is a string @Tim.

Comment: but `window.name` is just a reference, its type should depend on what it refers to . For comparison, in `node.js`, if I create and initialize `name` to be a string by `var name="hello"`, and then reassign to it a number, by `name=12`, then its type is number not string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086438/why-cant-i-change-the-type-of-name-in-firefox-web-console

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion from the output, node.js doesn't start the interpreter's work like the Firefox's web console - meaning in node.js similar to compiled languages it recognises it is a number. 
in the Firefox's web console it saves "12" as a string to the memory with var or use it only as a number with let without saving it to memory.