# Why can't I change the type of `name` in Firefox web console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-console

In Firefox web console, why can I change the type of `name2`

```
var name2=12
undefined

typeof name2
"number"

name2="hello"
"hello"

typeof name2
"string"
```

and not for `name`

```
typeof name
"string"

name=12
12

typeof name
"string"
```

?

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you explain how the linked post has answers to my question? The linked post doesn't ask the same question, nor have an answer to my question.

Comment: The situation is exactly the same - `name` on the top level will always refer to `window.name`, which must always be a string. As an answer there says, `The HTML5 spec requires that window.name is a DOMString`

Comment: After some discussion with @CertainPerformance I'm inclined to agree it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I would like to know from JS the language perspective: how to understand, implement or simulate a variable which is fixed to a type. Simply saying some language unrelated specification requires so is far from sufficient. Pointy already implied to address that issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086438/why-cant-i-change-the-type-of-name-in-firefox-web-console#comment98810859_56086450), but  CertainPerformance closed the post   around the same time, adversely preventing Pointy and other users from participation.

Comment: It's not possible with a *standalone variable*, but if you can refer to a property of an object, use getters and setters. Eg, to emulate the behavior of `name` here, have a setter which sets an internal variable to `String(passedVal)`, and a getter which returns that internal variable

Answer (score 0):

It's explicitly being cast to a string by JavaScript, since it's a readonly property of the global object (thanks Pointy).

Comment: Thanks. Can you manually create a variable that works in the same way (as if it is fixed to a type and any value assigned to it will be impliitly converted to the type)?

Comment: @Tim A variable that whenever it's updated, is called `toString` upon the new value?

Comment: It's not really a "reserved keyword", it's a non-writable property of the global (`window`) object.

Comment: @Pointy it is writable. see my example, where `name`'s value is changed to `12`

Comment: @Tim yea you're right; it just insists on the value being a string. It's not something I encounter in my day to day life :)  The point is that it's not a quirk of "JavaScript the language"; it's the runtime context.

Comment: @Pointy do you know how to manually create a variable like that?

Comment: @Tim you can't create a *variable* like that, but you can create an object property like that by using [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/getters-setters-for-dummies)

Comment: @Pointy why can't I create a variable like that? Isn't any global variable a property of the global object?

Comment: @Tim yes but the global object is not really a JavaScript object. It might be possible in some browsers to use `Object.defineProperty()` to do it; I've never tried.

Comment: Wow Firefox seems fine with it!

Comment: @Pointy What code did you use?

Comment: I'll add an answer; it literally never occurred to me to try this before. *edit* oh wait I can't. Well I just did `Object.defineProperty()` on `window` with a `get:` and `set:` function; the `set` function includes an explicit cast to string, and it behaves pretty much exactly like `name`.  Now other browser may or may not like this; IE11 in particular, but I don't know.