# Arrow function and simple function behaviour in an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, arrow-functions

Can any one explain `why arrow function is displaying "Ram" instead of 'Syam'` ?

What I know that `this` in arrow function points parent object and normal function points global object but result is different here

```
this.name="Ram"
var name="Ajay"
var obj ={
    name:"Shyam",
    show : () => console.log(this.name),
    show2: function (){console.log(this.name)}
  }
obj.show() // Ram
obj.show2() // Shyam
```

Comment: _"What I know..."_ - You might want to have another look at how (arrow) functions work ;)

Comment: be carefull by using global `name`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064897/var-name-and-window-name

Comment: @Andreas can you please give a solution instead of commenting and closing question ?

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar hi, do you run your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: *"What I know that `this` in arrow function points parent object normal function points global object ..."* Not at all. `this` inside an arrow function is resolved *lexically*, just like any other variable. `this` inside "normal" functions depends on *how* the function is *called*.

Comment: The links in the "it's a duplicate" box explain the behavior of `this`. Just read them.