# Typeof operator returning undefined for everything but 'strings'

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeof

I'm currently learning about the "typeof" operator in JavaScript, but the tutorial I'm following gives me different results than what I'm seeing in my console. Using anything other than 'strings' returns undefined. There are a few things I've seen about Automatic Semicolon Insertion, but they seem a bit more complicated than my current issue. Sorry, this might sound silly to the veterans, but for some reason I can't find the answer to the problem.

VS Code Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: Please include some runnable code as a snippet (not a screenshot).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+typeof+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: The typeof name is telling you that window.name is a string

Comment: Related: [Using the variable "name" doesn't work with a JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701) | [var name and window.name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11064897)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are evaluating code in two different contexts: your module, where your variables exists with a value and in the console where they are undefined, hence the result you see. You can add to `typeof` in your script directly to see the correct result.

Comment: If I am evaluating my code in two different contexts, shouldn't strings also return as undefined? I tried following a tutorial but I'm not sure why I'm getting different results. This is how he explained how to debug in the console and some beginner-friendly JavaScript concepts. I'm obviously going about learning JS in the wrong way. Ill try another source, thanks guys.

Comment: the `name` variable is always defined in the global (the console) scope. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name. Also note that `id` attributes declare global variables.