# How does this work in a standalone function?

Tags: javascript, this

I am getting confused regarding the `this` keyword in JS. I am not getting how this will work in a standalone function. I referred to many sites, all they are saying is when `this` is given in standalone function it will refer to the global object.

In that case for the following code I should get name as "steve" but I am getting undefined. I am trying to understand it but I couldn't pick up how it works.

```js
let name = "Steve";
    
function sayHelloOne() {
  console.log(`Hello, I'm ${this.name}`);
}
    
sayHelloOne();
```

Comment: `name` isn't a global variable.

Comment: The differences can be subtle.  For example, replace `let` with `var` and observe.

Comment: @David I tried with var also, I am getting undefined.

Comment: @robertklep it is global? It's just not attached to `window`.

Comment: @DaveNewton, when I am doing console name is not attached to Window then where it will be lying, Here I am declaring the value for let, I understand that let will not come inside global object but for var also it's not working.

Comment: @VLAZ I guess I missed that this is a browser-related question.

Comment: @Still_Learning don't use `name`. It's an already reserved property on `window`. [var name and window.name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11064897) | [What is the `name` keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2663740)

Comment: @VLAZ, Sure. I just checked name is reserved property. I changed the variable to player but I am still confused what that this inside function will refer to :(

Comment: @Still_Learning In addition to previous comment, it (somewhat) depends. If you run it from the JS console it's attached to `window` (at least in my current Chrome version), but I can't speak to anywhere else/other environments.

Comment: Depends on how it's executed. Check the duplicate. In short *usually* if not overridden it's going to be either the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode). But the value of `this` is always determined at call time for a regular function. It's never pre-determined.

Comment: @DaveNewton you mean you're getting the value for this.name when you invoke it?

Comment: @VLAZ I am not giving any strict so I can assume that my code is in loose mode right ?

Comment: If this is the *exact* code you're running - then yes. But that's not a general "yes, the function is in loose mode". Because this could also be context-dependent - code which is within ES6 exclusive constructs (classes, modules, generators, etc) is automatically in strict mode. Code might also be bundled with a `"use strict"` emitted by the bundler/transformer. However, if you don't do any of that, if your function is just placed in global scope and you've not explicitly enabled strict mode - then it's not going to be strict. In the browser you can check `this === window`