# Js split function giving wrong result

Tags: javascript

I was trying to split this string through "##" delimitter.

```js
var historycookie = "8.4707417,77.0463719:Sector 14:Gurgaon##28.3952729,77.3238274:Sector 15:Faridabad";
var history = historycookie.split("##");
alert(history.length);alert(history[0])
```

The `history.length` alert is giving me result as 6.
But ideally it should be 2.
The `history[0]` alert is giving undefined. Please help me with this as I am not able to get why this is happening.

Comment: Your code works for me on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fg8n36wq/). It alerts me with 2 then with the text before the `##`.

Comment: Even your snippet is working for me -- **EDIT** : When you click on `Run Snippet` several times, the first value increments

Comment: Yes, is there any way i can make sure that the js/jquery split function is called?

Comment: What kind of server are you using?  In some cases (like Coldfusion) # is a special character and could be causing odd behaviors as a result.

Comment: Related: [Using the variable “name” doesn't work with a JS object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/4642212).

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `alert` and use the debugging tools built-in in your browser. That way you can immediately see whether you’ve got the expected result and what the result is exactly otherwise. And paste your JS code in [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to see related mistakes immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON in javascript array is causing error Cannot read property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877236/json-in-javascript-array-is-causing-error-cannot-read-property). Found by searching “code:"var history" is:q”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"History" (or even "history") is a defined by the browser and representing your history.

```
history.length; // is returning size of entries in your history
history[0]; // undefined, because it is not an array
```

Just change the name of the history variable.