# Assign null to javascript var - ends up as String

Tags: javascript, null

I have initialized my variable as the following:

```
var name = null;
```

If I check it's value like this it doesnt do anything:

```
if(name == null) {
    alert("Name = null");
}
```

But if I change the if-clause to that, it works:

```
if(name == "null") {
    alert("Name = null");
}
```

Happy for every help.

Comment: yes im sure it works.

Comment: The behavior reported is incorrect. `null == "null"` is false.

Comment: Wow, that even works for type comparison. `if(name === 'null')` will also pass

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1435655

Comment: What is the exact code?

Comment: @m59 Doesn't apply, because of the OP's assertions.

Comment: @user2864740 ... are you suggesting that it's ever ok to use loose equality?

Comment: @m59 When did I imply that? However, using `===` here has *nothing* to do with the problem as both `null == "null"` and `null === "null"` are false.

Comment: @user2864740 "Doesn't apply"

Comment: @m59 First, off I do not believe it is always better to use `===`. Secondly, as I have argued, that question does not apply here.

Comment: @user2864740 could you provide an example of when it's not better to use type comparison?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the variable “name” doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely that you're running this is in global scope, in which case `name` refers to the [`Window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name) property. Assigning a value to this property automatically causes the value to be converted to a string, for example, try opening up your browser's console and typing this:

```
var name = 123;
alert(typeof name);
```

You'll most likely get an alert that reads `string`.

However, if you place this in an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (and ensure that you have a `var` declaration), it behaves as expected:

```
(function() {
    var name = null;
    if(name == null) {
        alert("Name = null"); // shows alert
    }
})();
```