# Can the "let" keyword be used in JavaScript to avoid global-scoped variables?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

I was doing a test in JavaScript and I noticed that using the `let` keyword like

```
let variable = "I am a variable";
console.log(window.variable);
```

did [not add a `variable` property to the `window` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572). Does this mean that it does not exist in the global scope?

Could I declare variables without having to scope them inside a function or an IIFE?

I did search for this but could not find anything. Everyone says to use functions like `{}()` or simply access a unique global variable that contains the code, but seeing this made me wonder if it could be used for the purpose of avoiding these things.

Comment: If the question is: "are top level `let`s a replacement for IIFEs and the encapsulation provided by a function's lexical scope?" then I think the answer would be a resounding no.  The ES2015 replacement for global namespace objects and many current uses of IIFEs is modules.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `let` statement cannot be used to avoid global variables in the way that you suggest. A top-level `let` statement will still create variables in the global scope, it just won't create them as properties of the "global object" (typically `window`).

```html
<script>
  'use strict';
  let fromLet = 'from let';
  var fromVar = 'from var';
</script>

<script>
  console.log(fromLet);        // 'from let'
  console.log(fromVar);        // 'from var'
  console.log(window.fromLet); // undefined
  console.log(window.fromVar); // 'from var'
</script>
```

This behaviour is primarily described in [Section 8.1.1.4: Global Environment Records of the ECMAScript 6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-environment-records). The gist of it is that there is a single global scope/namespace, but its values can be recorded in two different places. Global built-ins, `function` declarations, `var` declarations, and `function*` (generator) declarations are recorded as properties of the global object, while everything else global (from `let`, `const`, `class`, and other new constructs) is stored in an internal "environment record" which is not exposed as an object in the runtime.

Here are a few relevant excerpts to start from if you'd like to dig in to the details.

> A global Environment Record is used to represent the outer most scope that is shared by all of the ECMAScript *Script* elements that are processed in a common [Realm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-code-realms) ([8.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-code-realms)). A global [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-environment-records) provides the bindings for built-in globals ([clause 18](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-object)), properties of the global object, and for all top-level declarations ([13.2.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-static-semantics-toplevellexicallyscopeddeclarations), [13.2.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-static-semantics-toplevelvarscopeddeclarations)) that occur within a *Script*.

> Properties may be created directly on a global object. Hence, the object [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-environment-records) component of a global [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-environment-records) may contain both bindings created explicitly by *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, or *VariableDeclaration* declarations and binding created implicitly as properties of the global object. In order to identify which bindings were explicitly created using declarations, a global [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-environment-records) maintains a list of the names bound using its CreateGlobalVarBindings and CreateGlobalFunctionBindings concrete methods.

> #### Table 18 — Additional Fields of Global Environment Records
>
> `[[ObjectRecord]]`: [Object Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-environment-records)
>
> Binding object is the global object. It contains global built-in bindings as well as *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, and *VariableDeclaration* bindings in global code for the associated [Realm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-code-realms).
>
> `[[DeclarativeRecord]]`: [Declarative Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-declarative-environment-records)
>
> Contains bindings for all declarations in global code for the associated Realm code except for *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, and *VariableDeclaration* bindings.
>
> `[[VarNames]]`: [List](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) of String
>
> The string names bound by *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, and *VariableDeclaration* declarations in global code for the associated [Realm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-code-realms).