# Take let variable out of temporal dead zone

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variable-declaration

See this code:

```html
<script>
let {foo} = null; // TypeError
</script>
<script>
// Here I want to assign some some value to foo
</script>
```

The first script attempts to let-declare `foo` via a destructuring assignment. However, `null` can't be destructured, so the assignment throws a TypeError.

The problem is that then the `foo` variable is declared but uninitialized, so if in the 2nd script I attempt to reference `foo`, it throws:

```
foo = 123; // ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `foo' before initialization
```

And `let` variables can't be redeclared:

```
let foo = 123; // SyntaxError: redeclaration of let foo
```

Is there any way to take it out of the TDZ, so that I can assign values and read them?

Comment: BTW, I want to use `foo`, not workarounds like `window.foo`.

Comment: I'm guessing there's something interesting about the first script that makes assuring the validity of the initialization difficult.

Comment: @Oriol: `window.foo` [wouldn't work anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572) :-)

Comment: What environment are you executing this in (browser, version number)? How mature is its ES6 support, could it be that this is just a bug?

Comment: @Bergi well I'm not sure what the runtime can do about it. The TDZ in the global context has always seemed weird to me. I guess it'd be better if the exception in the first script block would cause the symbol to be removed as if there'd been no `let`, but that seems kind-of hackish because of hoisting.

Comment: @Bergi I tried Firefox and Chrome. And seems reasonable: a variable is in the TDZ between its declaration and its initialization. Here the initialization doesn't complete due to the error, so the variable remains in the TDZ. But if my reasoning is wrong and this is a bug, it would be a possible answer.

Comment: I just looked through the spec and this behaviour seems correct. I also found a third reasonable attempt which doesn't work either: `delete foo;`

Comment: You might want to post this to `es-discuss`, to spark a discussion whether this behaviour is intended and what could be done about it. Also, an example that doesn't rely on destructuring: `let foo = (() => {throw;})();`

Comment: @Bergi Yes, the destructuring was only a short way to throw an error during the assignment. Another example is `let foo = null.throw`. I will try es-discuss.

Comment: I [posted this to es-discuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/take-let-variable-out-of-temporal-dead-zone). It had already been discussed in [Global lexical tier](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/global-lexical-tier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. Temporal dead zone and restricted access to uninitialized `let` variable are expected to be unavoidaible. It's confusing and problematic, but intended and expected.

See [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) for details:

> NOTE let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment. **The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s LexicalBinding is evaluated**. A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer’s AssignmentExpression when the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created. If a LexicalBinding in a let declaration does not have an Initializer the variable is assigned the value undefined when the LexicalBinding is evaluated.\

So if variable wasn't initialized on declaration (and throwing before initialization obviously result in no initialization) it can't be accessed by any means.

But in fact, your issue is more complex than throwing assigment. It's architecture issue - you are depending on mutable global variables. It's big "no no no" and you should refactor your code to use explicit dependencies.