# Unable to access const variables through this in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I was exploring ES6 const keyword, everything is working for me, except some scoping issue which I am unable to understand.

I have a a simple js file

```
    const reducer = (state = 0,action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'Increment' : 
            return state+=1;
        case 'Decrement' :
            return state-=1;
        default :
            return state;       
    };
}

const {createStore} = Redux;
const store = createStore(reducer);

const getstate = () => {
    return store.getState();
}

// var getstate = () => {
//  return store.getState();
//} it is working

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.getstate());
    //console.log(getstate());   it is working
})
store.dispatch({type:'Increment'});
```

In my subscriber method this.getstate is returning `myjs.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: this.getstate is not a function` when I change `const getstate` to `var getstate` , it started working . Also when I changed `this.getstate` to `getstate`, it is also working

From browser console I can access getstate but I am unable to access this.getstate.
this here is in Window scope, but then why it is unable to access const variable?

Comment: Isn't its normal behaviour of `const` scope ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: What is printing `console.log(this);` inside the `subsribe` method?

Comment: @ianaya89 it is window object

Comment: Just drop the `this.`! `getstate` is a plain variable, not a property

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is when you create a variable with `const`,  this is is not accessible through `window` object (although the variable is global). I recommend to avoid creating global functionality and organice your code with practices as **IIFE** or **module patterns**.

If you want to keep your way, the best you can do is to add semantic to your code an attach de variable directly to the `window` object. Doing that your intention will be clear:

```
window.getstate = () => {
    return store.getState();
}
```

Comment: can you point me to some mdn doc or any doc which says const is not accessible through window object

Comment: I am trying to find that, I know it because I deal with this before and was my own conclusion.

Comment: @AvinashAgrawal [Do `let` statements create properties on the global object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

when you call `this.getState`, it will look from bottom to top to find `getState` variable.

```
global context which is window object -- TOP -- find getState in window object, if not return undefined
  ---> local context which is your current file -- find getState in this file, if not go up
    ----> current method which is () => { 
        this.getState() <-- find getState in this function, if not go up 
      } BOTTOM
```

According to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement.

that means when you defined `const getState`, it's only available in your current file.

When you defined `var getState` which is NOT block-scoped and `getState` variable will be available globally.

Comment: if const getState is only available in current file, then how it is accessible in console, I can access `getState` but not `this.getState`