# How to detect added global variables at runtime between two lines of code?

Tags: javascript

How to detect added global variables at runtime between two lines of code ?

I want to be able to tell what variable was added in between two lines of code at runtime without analyzing the source code. Just 1 variable is added.

Example:

```
"use strict";
//start

const myVariable = "10"; //detect this new variable

//end

const newVariableAdded = detectWhatIsNew();

// newVariableAdded should be "10" or "myVariable"
```

What I tried so far:

```
"use strict";

const notNew = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

const detectWhatIsNew = function () {
    let newString;

    let key;
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).some(function (key) {
        if (!notNew.includes(key)) {
            notNew.push(key);
            newString = key;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return newString;
};


//start    

const myVariable = "10"; //detect this new variable

//end

const newVariableAdded = detectWhatIsNew();

// newVariableAdded should be "10" or "myVariable"
```

Comment: [Possible XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what do you want to do actually? How do you expect a variable to be added during runtime? Please show an example how the new variable, `myVariable` in your example, is being added to the source while the program is running.

Comment: `detectWhatIsNew()` since when? Since the last call to that function? Since the last line before that function (which is actually whitespace)?

Comment: For why your code cannot work, have a look at [Do let statements create properties on the global object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Everyone here is saying that using `var` instead of `const` or `let` would solve the problem, but not (I know `const` and `let` declares variables locally independently of the scope). Variables declared with `var` are declared before the execution of that variable declaration, so what you can do is to set a new property on the global object, being this property the new variable (it has to be new, independently of `undefined`). Comprove it by running this: `(_ => { "use strict",  a = "10"; var a })()`. It won't throw any exception.

Comment: My bad, I was saying that your code was incorrect because you was returning only one info, but it's correct, I forgot to apply the edits about that in my answer

Comment: @FREEZE All I said is that you cannot detect `let`/`const` variables by inspecting `window`. Yes, hoisting is a problem for all variables; the global property is created right before a script is evaluated. But it's really unclear what the OP wants/needs anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `var` statement and split the code into multiple files so that the var statement does not get hoisted. There is a possibility to use a service worker to do split the files automatically.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="prepare.js"></script>
<script src="addVariable.js"></script>
<script src="detectNewVariable.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

prepare.js

```
"use strict";

const notNew = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(self);

const detectWhatIsNew = _ => {3
    /*returns an array*/
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(self).filter(key => {
        if (!notNew.includes(key)) {
            notNew.push(key)
            return true
        }
    });
};
```

addVariable.js

```
var myVariable = "10";
```

detectNewVariable.js

```
console.log(detectWhatIsNew()); // Array [ "myVariable" ]
```

Another way is to create globals using the `window.variable =` notation

Comment: "Service worker is a programmable network proxy, allowing you to control how network requests from your page are handled." see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

Answer (score 0):

`const` and `let` are block-scoped, they don't create properties on the global object, but it's accessible by all code running within your enviroment (if declared outside a block, in the top level).

Your code only works for `var` or if you don't use any statement.

I don't think there's some approach that can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What @EdmundoRodrigues says is almost correct, except that it works for `var` (IT DOESN'T in this case, but it works for inexistent global property assignment... "set", independently of `undefined`.

You can't detect the case of a variable (using `var` declaration) being added by `var` too, because the `var` statement declares variables instantly (sorry if my terms doesn't fit, English isn't my primary language), e.g.:

```
(_ => {
    a = "10"
    var a
    alert(self.a) // undefined on window (global object)
    // So the variable a can be assigned and used before the var
    // keyword comes.
    // If var [a] were not declared here, a would be global, or
    // if it was strict mode, an exception would have been
    // thrown.
}) ()
```

It's like this for `var`, except for `let` and `const`:

```
( _ => {
    a = "10" // Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined(…)
    let a
})()
```

Your function will only count global `var` statement used in next-separate scripts to be executed yet, and will also count fine any global object properties that were not existent earlier in the current executing expression/statement, independently of the `undefined` value.

`const` and `let` will be only visible in the entire scope until their declaration are executed, unlike `var`. And as @EdmundoRodrigues says, `let` and `const` variables are visible locally only, independently of the scope (even when the scope is global).

# Checking your code (note: I made a change to `detectWhatIsNew` to return all recent variables and declared `myVariable` with `var`).

```
"use strict"

const detectWhatIsNew = _ =>
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(self).filter(key =>
       !notNew.includes(key) && notNew.push(key))

const notNew = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(self)
var myVariable
console.log(detectWhatIsNew()) // an empty array
```

This won't work for `var`, but it does make sense! Because the presence of `var` is instant, the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(self)` call would have captured this `"a"` in any position.

```
console.log(notNew.indexOf( "myVariable")) // bigger than -1
```

But your function will still work for different ways of setting global variables, like:

```
self.myVariable2 = "19"
console.log(detectWhatIsNew()) // Array { "0": "myVariable2" }
```