# Can't get references to es6 classes in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to update my chrome extension with es6 classes. It works fine in the context of the background scripts. But I can't access this classes from within the ui page (i.e. the extension's popup) using chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().

background.js

```
function Foo() { ... }
class Bar { ... }
```

popup.js

```
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
new bg.Foo() // works
new bg.Bar() // Bar is undefined
```

I found this simple workaround:

background.js

```
class Bar {}
var exports = { Bar : Bar };
```

popup.js

```
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
new bg.exports.Bar() // works
```

Any ideas why it's not possible to get direct access to classes via the 'bg' object?

Comment: What does this have to do with ES6 classes? Does it work if you use ES5 `function` syntax?

Comment: As the example shows it does. Maybe I made it not clear enough? I changed it a little. Have a look at the code comments: bg.Foo (function syntax) is defined, but bg.Bar (class syntax) isn't.

Comment: Oops, I was blind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas why it's not possible to get direct access to classes via the 'bg' object?

Yes: `class`es do not [become properties of the global object even if they are global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572).

You don't need that `exports` object for a workaround, you can simply use

```
var Bar = class { … };
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!

Comment: That doesn't work in my case. Maybe de solutions is deprecated

Comment: @titusfx Nothing in the language changed.

Comment: I'm guessing is on chrome extension that you are not able to get the classes from background.js any more

Comment: @titusfx There's nothing special about classes though - you could not access *any* variables