# ecmascript 6 how to call a static class methode by reflection

Tags: javascript, reflection, ecmascript-6, static, es6-class

So I would like to call an es 6 static class method
By reflection using a string className and a string method name.
I have tried several ways.  unfortunately I don’t seem to find the correct way to do this.

By the way (as mentioned in the comments below) I am looking for a solution where I will get the name of the class and the name of the method from dom attributes so they need to be a string.

Can anybody help?

```js
class a{
 static b(nr){
   alert('and the answer is' + nr)
  }
}

let aClassName = 'a',
  aMethodeName = 'b',
    theCompleteCall = 'a.b',
    anArgument = 42;

//Reflect.apply(theCompleteCall,anArgument);
//window[aClassName][aMethodeName](anArgument);
//window[theCompleteCall](anArgument);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the fact that `let` and `class` not being declared in a global scope as you'd expect ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object)), you need to declare your class in a scope accessible, like so:

```
window.a = class a{
    static b(nr){
    alert('and the answer is' + nr)
  }
}

let aClassName = 'a',
        aMethodeName = 'b',
    theCompleteCall = 'a.b',
    anArgument = 42;
```

Then, you can call with reflection, like so:

`window[aClassName][aMethodeName](anArgument)`

So, the solution, is to provide a scope when declaring them, and access them through that scope.

Answer (score -2):

You're setting your variables to strings instead of the reference to your objects.

Comment: yes that is true and that is just the problem i like to solve
I will get the strings for attributes out of my dom I'll edit my question to make this more clear thanks