# Understanding scope of this keyword in JS

Tags: javascript

I read somewhere that in JS function (not the function), the scope of `this` keyword depends on the parent object calling it.

So I did something as simple as declaring a variable name in my Global Scope and calling it inside a function using this keyword

```
let name = "rohit" 

function something () {
console.log("this scope", this.name) 
}

something()
```

This didn't logged anything for `this.name`

**Question:** Can someone help me understand that why does it not log anything and not even return an error?

Comment: Hint: what is the object context of the call to `something`...

Comment: If you are calling `something()`, `this` will be `undefined`, at least in strict mode. Don't try to get the global object through that. (Which, btw, only has a [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) but [not your `let name`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572))

Comment: Because you have declared your variable with let and that simply have block level scope. Inside the function, you can not access outside let variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside function unless explicitly bound, `this` refers to window. So remove `let` keyword and `name` will be available in `window`

```js
name = "rohit"

function something() {
  console.log("this scope", this.name)
}

something()
```