# what is the difference between delete an undefined property and a property which declared by const, let using delete operatorin Javascript?

Tags: javascript, descriptor, configurable

Please look at the code,

```
foo = 1;
delete foo; // true
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this,'foo').configurable // true
var bar = 2;
delete bar; // false
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this,'bar').configurable // false
const fooBar = 3;
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this,'fooBar').configurable // undefined
delete fooBar; //false
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this,'noexist').configurable // undefined
delete noexist; // true
```

Based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the delete operator can work only with properties where their own descriptor configurable is `true`, so why there is a difference between delete "fooBar" and "noexist" returned value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables declared with `const` or `let` do not get assigned to the global object, hence your

```
const fooBar = 3;
```

does not show up when you do

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this,'fooBar').configurable
```

Only variables declared with `var` (or never declared at all, only assigned to, such as with `foo`) get assigned to the global object.

`delete` will [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Return_value):

> true for all cases except when the property is an own non-configurable property, in which case, false is returned in non-strict mode.

`window.foo`, having not been declared with `var`, `let`, or `const`, *is* a configurable property. `window.bar`, declared with your `var bar`, is assigned to `window` as a non-configurable property.

`delete fooBar` returns `false` because `fooBar`, although not actually a property on `window`, is a standalone identifier which cannot be deleted - `delete` will result in `false` whenever using `delete` like that would throw an error in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
const someVar = true;
delete someVar;
```

But `noexist` is not an identifier in your code, so there's no operation to even *attempt* to perform, so it returns `true` (and no error would be thrown in strict mode).

Answer (score 1):

Appending to the excellent answer from [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54284190/3888766). When you are assigning values to an undeclared variable like `foo = 1`, this happens:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {configurable: true, value: 1});
console.log(delete foo);
console.log(window.foo); //deleted from window
```

So the `configurable` attribute is true and you can delete this property using the `delete` keyword and it will return `true`.

When you declare a variable with `var bar = 2`, this is happening:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'bar', {configurable: false, value: 2});
console.log(delete bar);
console.log(window.bar); //still the property exists, delete does not work in a non-configurable property
```

Here the `configurable` attribute is `false` hence you won't be able to delete it using the `delete` keyword. In `use strict` mode, this will result in an `TypeError`.

Remember that in JavaScript, variable declaration in the global scope using `var` also adds that variable as a non-configurable property to the global object. But this behavior does not happen when you do the same using `const` and `let`.

To know more on the `let` and `const` variables and how they are stored, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776236/3888766). `let` and `const` variables are stored in a declarative environment record which is not accessible.

For the last case where the variable does not exist, still the `delete` returned `true` it is because that is how the delete operator is designed.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description):

> If the property which you are trying to delete does not exist, delete
>   will not have any effect and will return true

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, a variable declared with `const`, exists, but has the property `configurable` not set, that's why `delete` fails (and hence returns `false`) - the variable still exists.

Apparently deleting an inexistent variable is not an invalid operation, the goal of the operation is to delete the variable, and since it doesn't exist, the operation didn't take place, but the desired effect has been achieved (that's why returns `true`).

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* delete a constant as stated on MDN.

> > Any property declared with let or const cannot be deleted from the scope within which they were defined

So, when you delete constant `fooBar`, it returns a false. If something cannot be deleted then you will get false returned by delete statement. So for example, if you tried to delete a var like in `var x=20; delete x;//returns false`, then you would get a false value since var cannot be deleted within its scope. In the same way const and let variables cannot be deleted within their scopes and they would also return a false.

So, I would think like this : *if something cannot be deleted when it is existing then you get a false value returned by the delete statement*.

Also, if you try to delete a property that does not exist, then delete statement returns a true as stated on MDN.

> > If the property which you are trying to delete does not exist, delete will not have any effect and will return true.

So, when you delete `noexist` property on `this` object, it returns a true.