# Where is const stored when declared?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm kind of new to JS, while reading the document from mozilla.org, I read that when declaring a `const` in global, it doesn't become a property of the global object. My question is, if so, where is the property stored?

For example:

```js
const a = 'HI!';

function hello() {
  console.log(this.a); // undefined
}

hello();
```

This logs out undefined.

Instead of assigning it with

> global.a = 'HI!'

Are there other ways I can access `a` with `this`?

Comment: `const` doesn't create a property to the global object like `var` does. Refer the variables using their name. Notice, that in strict mode, `this` in `hello` would be `undefined`, and your code would throw an error.

Comment: Why do you want to access `a` via `this` in particular?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object), but maybe not a dup, since the subject is `let`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access a `const` or `let` variable (they behave identically in terms of access) that is *in an outer scope*, then you can do it by name

```js
const outerVariable = 'HI!';

function hello() {
  console.log("access from inner scope", outerVariable); 
}

hello();
```

That works unless the variable is shadowed - a new variable with the same name is created in an inner scope

```js
const outerVariable = 'HI!';

function hello() {
  const outerVariable = "impossible to access the outer declaration";
  console.log("access from inner scope", outerVariable); 
}

hello();
```

If you want to access it using the `this` context, then you can *set* the context of the function using [`Function#call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`Function#apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), or [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```js
const a = 'HI!';

function hello() {
  console.log("access from context", this.a); 
}

hello(); //undefined - it's not in the context

const newContext = {a : a}; //the new value of "this"
hello.call(newContext); //HI!
hello.apply(newContext); //HI!

const boundFunction = hello.bind(newContext); //"this" will always be newContext for boundFunction
boundFunction(); //HI!
```

In this case `.call()` and `.apply()` are equivalent but in general [they are subtly different when more parameters are passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Comment: I'm a little confused here, so what you mean is that if I declare a variable _a_ with `const` at global scope, I still can't access it using `global.a`?

Comment: @user8480342 `let` and `const` variables do not add a property to the global object when declared in the global scope. It's how their spec was written, so the behaviour is consistent with that. It is *different* to `var` declarations that explicitly do add a property to the global object when declared in the global scope.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Information about **const** :

With const you can define immutable variables (constants).

```
const PI = 3.1415;
PI = 5; // "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

However, new items can still be pushed into an array constant or added to an object.

```
const someArr = [3, 4, 5];
someArr.push(6);
```

Now, accessing value inside `function` using **this** keyword , will give value only for functions block scope .

So, to access const a inside function you can use :

```
const a = 'HI!';

function hello() {
  console.log(this.a); // undefined <- this refer to function hello's scope
  console.log(a);   // HI!
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response, in your last code, I added `var a = 'Hello~'` in the `hello` function, but it still logs out `undefined`. If _this_ is referring function hello's scope, why can't I still access it. I thought when you declare a function outside of an object, `this` simply means the global object, since console loging _this_ in the global scope gives you _window_ object or _global_ object.

Comment: you can direct access var a inside console log in hello function , no ned to use this.a

Answer (score 1):

It is declared in the block you are in. You can still access it from the same block scope (and the scopes that are declared in it), but not with window.a or global.a from any scope.

So - this would work:

```
const a = 1;

function b() {console.log(a);}
```

These however, would not:

```
window.a;
global.a;
```

Comment: The arrow functions aren't explicitly needed here, the function would become a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: True - I edited the post to make it less confusing. @James