# Why global let declarations get overridden by unscoped variables?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, var, let

When we create a variable without specifying `let` or `var` it gets added to window object in browser. For example

```js
function change(){
    val = 20;
}
change();
console.log(window.val); //20
console.log(val);  //20
```

Here I am getting both console logs print value `20`. But I do the same using `let` it doesn't get added to window object. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object) with the explanation why this is happening.

```js
let val = 20;
console.log(window.val); //undefined
console.log(val); //20
```

Now, in the below code, can someone explain, when I assign an un scoped variable inside the function why it is not getting added to `window` scope? Instead how it is changing the value of the variable declared with `let`

```js
let value = 10;
function change(){
    value = 20;
}
change();
console.log(window.value); //undefined 
console.log(value); //20  why this is 20?
```

Answer (score 2):

MDN says this about [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description):

> The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global. If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.

MDN says this about [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2):

> Variables declared by `let` have their scope in the block for which they are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks. In this way, `let` works very much like `var`. The main difference is that the scope of a `var` variable is the entire enclosing function:

They both end up in a scope which is then propagated to child scopes but which scope they end up in and how they go about determining that scope is different.

Note that the entirety of a `<script>` element does have an implicit block and this implicit block inherits `window` as an ancestor scope. Variable declared by `var` end up scoped into `window` while variables declared by `let` are scoped into this implicit block.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variables with let in the top-level of your script lets you access it inside your entire script and even outside. Inside your function, you are not assigning a value to an unscoped variable.

Even if you were to write your function as below, it would not assign to the window object as it would then be function scoped.

```
function change(){
var value = 20;
}
```