# Sharing Variables Between Files (Without Globals)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It was my understanding that variables created with `let` in Javascript cannot be global.  I *thought* that meant that the variable only lived in that particular file.

However, when I make a simple/contrived example:

A.js:

```
let a = 5;
```

B.js:

```
console.log(a);
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="B.js"></script>
```

it logs 5!  Strangely though if I log `window.a`, that logs as `undefined`, so a global variable is *not* being created.

My question is, how is the variable getting shared between files without being a global variable?

Comment: it's in scope of the global scope :)

Comment: @Bergi, that's not the same question. This talks about whether the particular scope that top level `let` occupies is shared between scripts or not. Your question addresses whether or not it exists on the `global` / `window` object.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1541563), but not a duplicate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The duplicate explains how `let a` declares a global variable without `a` become a property of `window`. Seems like it answers machineghost's question perfectly fine.

Comment: The related question answers _Do these declarations create properties on the global object?_ It does not even address the fact that the variable is shared between synchronously loaded scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stays inside the current scope, the most outer block scope (or global scope as Bergi so nicely mentions), so this would work

```html
<script>
let world = 'world';
</script>
<script>
console.log( `hello ${world}` );
</script>
```

Where as this would not

```html
<script>
{
  let world = 'world';
}
</script>
<script>
console.log( `hello ${world}` );
</script>
```

it really doesn't matter that you are using 2 different files. In the end, all the scripts that get loaded get put behind each other, optimized and executed

Comment: Stupid question, how is `{  let world = 'world'; }` valid Javascript?  That looks like a let statement inside an object literal (ie. invalid JS) to me?

Comment: @machineghost it's a block scope ;)

Comment: Wackiness.  I've been using Javascript for a decade and never knew block scopes were a thing.

Comment: "*most outer block scope*" - it's called the global scope for simplicity :-)

Comment: @Bergi you always know how to say it in a correct simple way :D

Comment: I think the most confusing thing about all of this to me is that I've heard so many times "use `let` or `const` instead of `var` because they avoid creating global variables, which as we all know are bad".  This new understanding completely destroys that, and now (in terms of preventing file A from accidentally messing with something from file B) `let`/`const` seems to offer no benefit over `var`.  But it's all making more sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular variable in the global scope.

Using multiple script sources doesn't mean using multiple interpreters.

Comment: "regular variable in the global scope" doesn't make sense; how is that different from a global variable?

Comment: It's not different. You just can't access it as a property of window, as it is never assigned to window. For that you would have to do window.a = 5 instead.

Comment: I guess this just doesn't match any explanation I've been given of global variables before.  The fact that they were a property of window and the fact that they could be accessed anywhere used to be inherently linked together, so separating the two goes against my previous education.  Thanks!