# If not window who does keep reference to the variable?

Tags: javascript, reference, this, strict

The following code I run in three different ways but only one works without errors.
I don't understand why. Could you please tell me if not window who does keep reference to the variable?

**SCRIPT:**

```
'use strict';

let s = function(){};
```

**TRY 1************************************

```
s();
```

**CONSOLE: OK**

**TRY 2************************************

```
window.s();
```

**CONSOLE: ERROR**

TypeError: window.s is not a function

**TRY 3************************************

```
this.s();
```

**CONSOLE: ERROR**

TypeError: this.s is not a function

---

Comment: [That's just how `let` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). It's in the scope of the file, why would it need to be a property of some object?

Comment: Related: [Do let statements create properties on the global object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let can be only available inside the scope it's declared (scope to the block)
use **var** , which defines a variable globally ....

Try

```
'use strict';
var s = function(){};
```

```js
'use strict';

var  s = function(){};
// TRY 1**********************************

s();

// TRY 2**********************************

window.s();


// TRY 3**********************************

this.s();
```

Answer (score 0):

`let` doesn't create a property of `window`.

> Just like const the let does not create properties of the window object when declared globally (in the top-most scope) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#:%7E:text=let%20allows%20you%20to%20declare,function%20regardless%20of%20block%20scope.).