# In JavaScript; does a let variable declared outside of a block get a global scope?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript; does a let variable declared outside of a block become a global scope?

```
let letVariable = 2;
console.log(letVariable);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do let statements create properties on the global object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object)

Comment: Not really. I can see that the letVariable is accessible but not bind to the window object. Does it mean that the letVariable is a global variable but not a property of the window object?

Comment: @HomTom have a read of all the answers. They talk specifically about whether let outside any blocks is equivalent to a var.

Comment: Defining it outside of a block will make it accessible to other functions. It is not shoved onto the window object. So it is global in the sense anything can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly.

There is no "outside of a block", because even if you use it on the blank page, it is in the "main/global block" **but only in the same script**. its not available from other scripts.

Comment: I don't agree, as it won't be accessible in other scripts.

Comment: I agree. so it is bound on the script itself as "script-global". Would that be a better answer?

Comment: I guess so? But it's not a term used elsewhere so it may confuse things.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. It means that it would be a global variable but only inside its own file where it's declared but it's not accessible by any other file as it's not bind to window object; is that correct?

Comment: @epascarello’s comment is spot on