# How to find the prototype object of a Class?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, scope, executioncontext

Learning about classes, prototypes etc. and it's finally all coming into place for me (which is quite exciting to say the least :)))
However, my question has to do with finding the object prototype of a Class, where I should in theory find the its methods.

For example:

```
class Color {
    constructor(r, g, b, name) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        this.name = name;
    }
    innerRGB() {
        const { r, g, b } = this;
        return `${r}, ${g}, ${b}`;
    }
    rgb() {
        return `rgb(${this.innerRGB()})`;
    }
    rgba(a = 1.0) {
        return `rgba(${this.innerRGB()}, ${a})`;
    }
}

const red = new Color(255, 67, 89, "tomato");
```

Where are innerRGB(), rgb() and rgba() stored? I can't find them on the window object. Where are they? Where is the class Color stored?

When I enter Color() in the console, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Color cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I'm clear on the inner workings of constructor functions, what's unclear to me is where the prototype resides and how I can access and inspect it.

Comment: They are on `Color.prototype`. As to the error message near the end of your question: that is a different, unrelated question: you should create an instance with `new Color()`, just like the error message says.

Comment: `red.__proto__` or `Color.prototype`

Comment: @RahulKumar `red.__proto__` points to `Color.prototype`

Comment: yes correct, both way you can get what you need

Comment: Try logging the following on the console: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(red))`

Comment: @trincot thank you for your answer. However, what I'm eager to know is: where is Color.prototype? As in in which scope? I can't find it on the global object (window), so where is it? Thanks again.

Comment: It is not a global *variable* if that is what you are looking for. It is created when the class is created. The class (which is a constructor function) is represented in a global variable `Color`, and the prototype, that will be used for actual instances of that class, is a property of that global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are object relationships for your code snippet:

[image]

The object in the middle, `red.__proto__`, a.k.a `red.constructor.prototype`, a.k.a. `Object.getPrototypeOf(red)` a.k.a. `Color.prototype` is where methods are stored.

The scope of the class `Color` itself (which is `ƒ Color` on the diagram) is its containing block, like with any other variable. In Javascript, classes are functions and functions are variables:

```
{
   // block started

   class Color { // it's the same as "let Color = function...
      ...
   }

   // block ended

}

// "Color" doesn't exist here
```

Comment: What visualisation tool is that? Why does it still use the deprecated  `__proto__`?

Comment: Thank you for the diagram, it's helpful to visualize things. Everything in it makes sense but for one thing, in which scope is Color? So the middle box, where is it? It's not on the global object, so where is it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Vayl `class`es can be global [without being properties of the global object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572)

Comment: One last tangent if you don't mind, what kind of tool are you using to create these diagrams? Seems very handy. Thanks for everything :) @Bergi

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access prototype of the instance use `__proto__` field. If you want to see the prototype on a class itself use `prototype` field.

What happens when you create an instance the `__proto__` field of an instance is set to `prototype` field of a class.

```
instance.__proto__ === Class.prototype
```

Comment: No, don't use `.__proto__`, it's deprecated. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf`.