# Cannot see a global variable declared by var/let under globalThis

Tags: javascript, object, global-variables, global, delete-operator

In D.Flanagan's 'Javascript the Definite Guide' there's an example:

```js
var x = 1;
console.log(delete globalThis.x)
```

When I console log this code in node v14.15.1 then instead of false I get true. When console logging globalThis then x is not there. If I declare x without var or let then it becomes a part of global object. Funnily when I ran this code here on Stack Overflow then it behaved as Flanagan explained.

Can somebody please explain to me why global variables declared with var/let won't get a part of globalThis in my environment?  Is this because the version of Node I'm using or something else?

Comment: try using `global` instead of `globalThis` in node.js

Comment: [Using `let x` *never* creates a property on the global object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572).

Comment: Using `global` didn't work either @mrJQuery .  It turns out that all the code in a node file is wrapped in a function making all variables you declare there local.

Comment: so is there a way to get the every declarations in global or globalThis