# Explain the running result of this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```js
const obj = {
    length:10,
    log() {
       console.log(this.length)
    }
}
obj.log() // 10

const length = 20
const fn = obj.log
fn() // 0

const arr = [30,obj.log]
arr[1]() // 2
```

Why the fn() result is `0` ? if use `var length = 20` instead of `const length = 20` the result is `20`, how this happening?

Comment: In case it's not clear, you're referring to the value that is written by console.log, rather than the return value from the function.

Comment: Required reading: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: @jarmod what's the difference?

Comment: "*if use var length = 20 instead of const length = 20 the result is 20, how this happening?*" [Do let statements create properties on the global object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079)

Comment: I'm saying that your use of the word "result" is ambiguous and some readers may initially think you are referring to the return value of the called function rather than its logged output. I'm simply clarifying what you (presumably) mean.

Comment: @jarmod why the logged output is 0? what's the return value of called function?

Comment: In the `const length = 20` variant, the call to `fn()` logs `window.length` because `this` is actually `window` when run in a browser (and it's `global` when run in Node.js), whatever value that is. In your case, it's zero. I just ran this in the Chrome debugger and it logged 2 (which is the value of `window.length`). Modify your obj.log function to also log the value of `this`. You'll see that it changes from the `obj` object to window/global. And read the links that @VLAZ offered earlier.

Comment: @jarmod. what... you logged 2?

Comment: Yes, it logged 2.  The `this` object in that scenario is `window` and its length property is 2.

Answer (score 1):

the differences lies in what `this` means in the context of execution of the function `log`

in the first case `this` = `obj` so this.lenght = 10

in the second case `this` is the `window` object in the browser so if you use `var` or if you write `window.length` it returns the value you set

in the third case this means the array so it returns the array length

```js
const obj = {
    length:10,
    log() {
       console.log(this.length)
    }
}
obj.log() // 10

const length = 20
const fn = obj.log
fn() // 0
window.length = 20
fn() // 20

const arr = [30,obj.log]
arr[1]() // 2
```

Comment: how 0 output from that log?