# Arrow Function this prints var but does not print let variable

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```js
var key = "outer value";
let obj = {
  key:"obj value",
  func:()=> this.key,
}

console.log(obj.func());
```

But when the var is changed to let, the result is undefined. Please guide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616262/5605822

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: In the above code, `this` in your arrow function refers to the global object (if being run in non-strcit mode). In the browser, `this` refers to the `window`, so you are accessinng `window.key`. When you define a variable with `var` in the global scope, it gets added to the `window` object , so `var key = ...` allows you to access the value using `window.key`, when you use `let` though, the variable name doesn't get added to `window` as a property.

Comment: Please have a look at this [what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @NickParsons then where does `let key="outer value";` get added if not window?

Comment: @Abhijeet internally it gets added to something called a "declarative environment record" which is part of the global envrionment/scope, but there are is no JS APIs or objects that allow you to access those bindings like you can with `window`. You can see more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776236/5648954)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An arrow function does not have its on this, It always uses parent this

Your code works because the key is global scope(this)

```
let key = "outer value";
let obj = {
  key:"obj value",
  func:()=> key,
}
console.log(obj.func());
```

This will not work because key is local scope not inside this

```
function test() {
  var key = "outer value";
  let obj = {
    key: "obj value",
    func: () => this.key,
  };

  console.log(obj.func()); // undefined
}
test();
```

This Will work

```
function test() {
  this.key = "outer value";
  let obj = {
    key: "obj value",
    func: () => this.key,
  };

  console.log(obj.func()); // outer value
}
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let key = "outer value";
let obj = {
  key:"obj value",
  func:()=> key,
}

console.log(obj.func()); //--> Outer Value


var key = "outer value";
let obj = {
  key:"obj value",
  func:()=> key,
}

console.log(obj.func()); //--> Outer Value
```

The answer would be same even if this keyword is not used

```js
var key = "outer value";
let obj = {
  key:"obj value",
  func:()=> key,
}

console.log(obj.func());
```

Comment: In OP's code, the result is different when `var` is changed to `let`, but in this code it will be the same. So they're not the same...