# How to access items in other page's global Declarative Environment Record -- if possible?

Tags: javascript, iframe, ecmascript-6, global-variables, lexical-scope

I'm trying to find out if a script running in a wrapper page can access and use certain JavaScript object types  defined on another page which is loaded in an iframe.  And no, I'm not trying to set up a phishing site :)

All global `var` declared variables as well as functions are added as properties on the other page's `window` object.  These I can access perfectly fine, assuming I've set up the security correctly (like cross site scripting etc.).  This way I can also use these from within the wrapping page by using e.g.

```js
// other page's javascript:
function MyFunction() {return 42}

// wrapper page's javascript:
let iframe = document.getElementsById('frameID') // or such
window.MyFunction = iframe.contentWindow['MyFunction']
console.log(MyFunction()) // should say 42
```

But `let` and `const` declared variables, as well as `class` objects do not partake in this behavior.  They are only stored in the other page's global declarative environment record, and not in its global object environment record.

Is there a way that I can get access to the object types that are only stored in the other page's declarative environment record?  It wouldn't surprise me if it's browser dependent, or if its not possible at all due to security concerns or 'who needs that' or such...

For a little background: I'm the creator of [Jazillionth](https://carlcolijn.github.io/Jazillionth/), and I got some feedback from a user that tried to test a `class` object, which my script failed to access.  He could store the class in a regular `var` like `var MyClass = class {}` as a workaround, but that sort of defeats my purpose of Jazillionth (of not being obtrusive wrt your pages under test)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to resort to `eval` (or similar) to access [those variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object) that are not properties of the global object:

```
const iframeMyFunction = iframe.contentWindow.eval('MyFunction')
```

Comment: Very nice!  I tested it out, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Now I can relay it back to that user and put a smile on his face too :)