# How to avoid shadowing the window.close function?

Tags: javascript, shadowing, global-scope

I have a function named `close` in a js file that can't be renamed for some reason.  Now whenever I want to use `window.close` function (to close the browser tab) I can't: my `close` function overrides that functionality.

Is there a way to call the main `window.close` function to close the browser tab?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
    function close() {
        alert('hi')
    }
    function myFunction() {
        window.close()
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*that can't be renamed for some reason*" - tell us which reason that is and we can tell you how to work around that. Renaming or at least re-scoping that function is the only proper solution.

Comment: its a header file and the testers are scared to test it thoroughly on all pages. Its a huge website. We are not sure where is this close function called. Even if we find it, the testing scope is a problem They will have to test it throughout the site.

Comment: Well you'll have to test the entire site anyway if you want to change what a `window.close()` call is doing - previously it would have alerted 'hi', now it'll close the window. If you're scared of the code, that's all the better reason to refactor it :-)

Comment: Why not instead consider what your close does and name it accordingly? Like closeModal, closeDropdown, closeDeal, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `close` variable from being property of the global object to be a global variable only by declaring it with `let` or `const` - see [Do let statements create properties on the global object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776079/1048572). So with

```
/* do not change to function declaration or var, as that would break `window.close`! */
const close = function close() {
    alert('hi')
};
```

your `myFunction` implementation

```
function myFunction() {
    window.close()
}
```

will just begin to work.

(Of course, this will break all old code that did call `window.close()` and expected it to `alert('hi')` - but imo that was a bug anyway).

Comment: This works and is a marvelous piece of code. I'm using this. Thanks Bergi

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you cannot modify the js file that contains the `close` function at all. There's a trick that allows you to "restore" an overwritten built-in function using a fresh `window` object from an iframe.

> You can't see it's working here because the emulator is running inside of an iframe.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

  <script>
    function close() {
      alert('hi')
    }

    function myFunction() {
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.append(iframe);

      // calling original window.close function
      iframe.contentWindow.close.call(window);

      iframe.remove();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this thing works!, thank you Hao Wu