# JavaScript in operational throw a exception?

Tags: javascript

code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var name = [2,3,4];
  var a = (1 in name);
  console.log(a);
</script>
```

but throw error

[image]

if code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var names = [2,3,4];
  var a = (1 in names);
  console.log(a);
</script>
```

no error! why?  test on firefox!

Comment: name ... is actually `window.name` which is always a string and can't be changed from a string

Comment: @JaromandaX: That's an answer. :-) We've had this question a couple of dozen times, but it's **really** hard to find originals to use as close-targets...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I'm sure I learned that here on SO - looking for the dupe :D

Comment: Doesn't throw up in Chrome either. Logs true.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak - it does not, you did it wrong

Comment: @Abhitalks: Nope, fails in Chrome too. The key here is that the code must be at global scope. If it's inside a function (like jsFiddle's default `onload` handler), it'll work as-is.

Comment: @JaromandaX kudos to you man.!!

Comment: @Abhitalks ... the **first** code snippet doesn't work, the **second* does ... it's the same in firefox and chrome at least ... if you think the first code works, you did it wrong

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nope it does not fail in chrome if you use variable named as 'names' instead of 'name'

Comment: that's exactly what the question says ... `name` fails, `names` works

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ahh.. yes of course. wrapped in `load`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I've just used one. If you find a better (earlier?) duplicate target, let me know :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Nice one. We *knew* it was there. :-)

Comment: thanks @Bergi - I can stop looking now :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: In fact I've looked closer now and there are [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=window.name+string). The [earliest occurence](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/1048572) seems to be from May '12, and is answered quite well (if a bit short maybe). What do you think, should we use it as a canonical target or are there better ones?

Answer (score -1):

Since there is a possibility of scope issues with the variable `name`, do create a scope with something like this:

```
(function() {
  var name = [2,3,4];
  var a = (1 in name);
  console.log(a);
})();
```