# JS object behavior is different when I change the property value

Tags: javascript

I'm completely new to JS and trying to learn on my own. Using below code -

```
var me = {
    name: {first:"justin"}
},
name = me.name;

name = {first: "alexis"};
```

Why would `document.write(me.name.first + "</br>");` return `justin`?

and

why would `document.write(this.name.first);` doesn't return anything?

Please can you explain me?

Thanks,
Me

Comment: because the doc.write code is not defined inside the object you created, so `this` has a differant context (its context is whatever object the code exists as part of, in this case, the page, I think). using `me` fully qualifies the instance of the object, so it works correctly.

Comment: In what context are you executing those `document.write()`s? Right after the snippet you posted?

Comment: What do you expect `me.name.first` to be? You never assign any other value to `me.name` or `me.name.first` (that is, you have no `me.name = ...` or `me.name.first = ...` statements in your code).

Comment: As for why `this.name.first` doesn't work as you expect, see [Using the variable “name” doesn't work with a JS object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/710446). `this.name` is probably being set to the string `[object Object]`, which does not have a `first` property.

Comment: acdcjunior - Yes, that's correct. This code is part of video tutorial and I'm trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: @apsillers - This makes sense now. Thank you for your help. So, avoid using "name" as the variable or object name in global execution context, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the variable name `name` to other string, for example: `n`. Everything will work perfect.

```
var me = {
   name: {first:"justin"}
},
n = me.name;

n = {first: "alexis"};
```

The reason is `this.name.first` will refer to `window.name.first`. But `window.name` has special usage in javascript and has to be a string.

Comment: That explains. So, avoid using "name" as the property or variable name. Basically, treat them as reserve words, is it good practice? Can I use them inside the objects ("me" in my example).

Thank you again.

Comment: @DV27 You can use it as property name. Also you can use it as a local scope variable name. Just avoid using it as a global variable name.