# Add value to existing value

Tags: javascript, html

When a user types in an input box, I want their name to be displayed **after** the text 'hello'. Instead of doing this, the word 'hello' is removed and replaced by their name.

```js
var name = document.getElementById('username');
var div = document.getElementById('displayname');

name.onkeyup = function() {
  div.value = name.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="username">
<input type="submit" id="displayname" value="Hello">
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t01prhx4/

Comment: There’s one subtle error in your code in the snippet: [do not use the variable name `name`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/4642212) (in a global scope), as it is a global string property of `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple add hello before the

```
var name = document.getElementById('username');
var div = document.getElementById('displayname');

name.onkeyup = function(){
   div.value = "Hello " + name.value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/98c16uv5/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was this simple! I was thinking about concatenating the values and going down that route....

Comment: If you don't want use the literal value  you can set a var with "hello " an refer to this var ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
name.onkeyup = function(){
    div.value = 'Hello ' + name.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
 name.onkeyup = function(){
        div.value = 'Hello ' + this.value;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
var name = document.getElementById('username');
var div = document.getElementById('displayname');

name.onkeyup = function(){
    div.value = 'Hello ' + name.value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oapfc1Lo/