# Javascript coerces variable to string why?

Tags: javascript

Consider the followng code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
     var name = 0;
        while ( name < 6 ) {
            console.log('Masha');
            name = name + 1;
            console.log(name);
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output in Chrome Developer Tools to be:

```
Masha
name.html:9 1
name.html:7 Masha
name.html:9 2
name.html:7 Masha
name.html:9 3
name.html:7 Masha
name.html:9 4
name.html:7 Masha
name.html:9 5
name.html:7 Masha
name.html:9 6
```

Instead I get

```
Masha
name.html:9 01
name.html:7 Masha
name.html:9 011
```

Why is this the case? It also happens if I copy/paste the code directly. If I chop the `n` of of `name` then it does work. If I change the variable to `myName` it does work. Why is it coerced to a string? I'm using `Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)` of Chrome. It also happens in Firefox `52.0.2 (64-bits)`.

This doesn't happen when I run the code in node or in Internet Explorer.

[image: example output]

Comment: Check the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object)

Comment: Apologies for the double post.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're using `name` at global scope in a browser. Browers already have a built-in `name` global (specifically, the property `name` of `window`, which is the window's name) which is always a string. Either:

1. Use a different name, or better:
2. Don't use a global

This is a great example of why not using global variables is a good idea. :-)

Here's an example of #2:

```js
(function() {
    var name = 0;
    while ( name < 6 ) {
        console.log('Masha');
        name = name + 1;
        console.log(name);
    }
})();
```

Now that `name` isn't a global anymore (you're *shadowing* it with a local variable called `name`), all is well.

In browsers that properly support ES2015's `let`*, you can also use `let`, because variables created with `let` (and `const` and `class`) are globals, but not properties of the global object. Your `let name` shadows the global that comes from the property even at global scope:

```js
let name = 0;
while ( name < 6 ) {
    console.log('Masha');
    name = name + 1;
    console.log(name);
}
```

But again, just not using a global is best.

---

* Note: Some browsers have `let` but not with correct ES2015 semantics, such as IE11 (it's missing some important functionality around `let` in a `for` loop header declaration, it doesn't give each loop iteration its **own** `a`, with consequences for closures created in the body of the `for`), but most modern browsers — certainly Chrome, Firefox, and Edge — support it properly. And IE11's `let` works in the situation above (just not the `for` loop situation) as well.