# Why running same code is different between node env and chrome console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, scope

```
var name = "Global";

function funcA() {
    var name = "FunA";
    return function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

funcA()();
```

I run the code above on my terminal using node and return `undefined`
but in chrome console it will return `Global`.

Why is this happened?

Comment: sorry, just edit the code and it will print Global then undefined, why?

Comment: I see the log message `Global` followed by the return value `undefined` in both Node (admitted ancient 0.12.4) and Chrome. Can you show a screenshot of what Node does? In **no** environment does `funcA()()` have a return value (other than the default `undefined` due an absence of a `return`ed value). `function() { console.log(this.name); }` has zero `return` statements inside it.

Comment: Also, beware [the danger of using a global variable called `name`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/710446), which will be stringified in browser code. (Not a problem here, since it is a string, but may cause trouble for other types.)

Comment: Are you running this code as a module? (Top-level variables in modules are not global, which would explain why you see different values logged.)

Comment: @apsillers I believe he runs it via `node test.js`...

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Running this script in Browser environment forces that top-level var to become a property of the global `window` object. Then per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> Since the following code is not in strict mode, and because the value of this is not set by the call, this will default to the global object , which is window in a browser.

So calling `console.log(this.name);` inside that function means that `this` would be a link to the global `window` object, which would have `name` property. And the value of `window.name` is "Global".

**2.** NodeJS has no `window` object, but it has `global` object instead. Running script in NodeJS environment breaks on two situations: 
**(a)** running as module (e.g. via `node test.js`) and **(b)** running not as module (e.g. directly in node console).
The second case **(b)** works the same as for Browser: `global` would receive `name` property and `this` would be a link to `global`,
so the value of `this.name` would be equal to `global.name` and would be "Global".

But first case **(a)** is different, per [NodeJS doc](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> Object The global namespace object.
>
> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. This means that within the browser var something will define a new global variable.
>   In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node.js module will be local to that module.

So that top-level var becomes just a local variable in the Node environment, and since `global` has no `name` property, 
calling `console.log(this.name)` shows `undefined`.

Comment: but is node doesn't have global object?

Comment: So, my understanding is this answer implicitly suggests that the OP's code is running inside of a module so that the top-level `var name = "Global";` does not create a global variable, correct? Indeed, that would explain it, if true, though I think you should make that assumption more explicit.

Comment: @apsillers If you define `global.name = "Global";` instead of `var name = "Global"`, it will work.

Comment: @Dreams: It does. Every JavaScript environment has a global object. It's not standardized which global variables exist by default though.

Comment: @apsillers Variables declared via `var` do not become `global` object properties in Node, as they do for `window` in Browser.

Comment: @dhilt It's not correct. I've tested it on Node v9.0.0 right now

Comment: @SerG The issue here is that global variables *do* become properties of `global` *within the REPL*, but do not when code is run as a "module".The confusing distinction here is that direct execution of a file (`node foo.js`) is "modular" execution. Indeed, running the OP's file as `node test.js` does not add a property to `global` whereas running it in the console *does* add a `global` property.

Comment: @apsillers That's exactly what I mean in my answer.

Comment: @dhilt: They probably are if they are defined in global scope. But you are usually working with modules (and thus module scope) in Node.

Answer (score 0):

`var` in top level scope defines variable in `Global object`.

`this` in your anonymous function call is pointed to `Global object` in case of browser or interactive Node session but to `exports-object` in case of script running as node module.

It's until strict mode...