# What's wrong with the variable name in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

```js
var name = ['name1', 'name2', 'name2'];
console.log(name, name.length);
// name1,name2,name2 17
```

**AND**

```js
var names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name2'];
console.log(names, names.length);
// (3) ["name1", "name2", "name2"] 3
```

**What's wrong with the variable `name` in JS?**

Comment: Its a reserved word. Check this: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: [`name` is a property of the global `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). You cannot save anything but a string to it

Comment: That's one reason why you should avoid to define own variables in the global scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the variable "name" doesn't work with a JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object)

Comment: @Sunil `name` is _not_ a reserved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) `Gets/sets` the name of the window.

```
string = window.name;
window.name = string;
```

The name of the window is used primarily for setting targets for hyperlinks and forms. Windows do not need to have names.

It has also been used in some frameworks for providing cross-domain messaging (e.g., [SessionVars](https://github.com/ironboy/mongresto/tree/master) and Dojo's [dojox.io.windowName](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/)) as a more secure alternative to JSONP. Modern web applications hosting sensitive data should however not rely on window.name for cross-domain messaging but instead rather utilize the postMessage API.

> Don't set the value to something `unstring` since its get method will call the `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is because *window.name* is reserved. The type should be string. So when you declare *name* via *var* and assign an array, it will be implicitly converted to string.

You could try this code:

`let name = ['name1', 'name2', 'name2'];
console.log(name, name.length);
// (3) ["name1", "name2", "name2"] 3`

Because *let* variable will not be attached into *window* object.

You could refer this MDN link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name.