# typeof name returns string even though number was assigned

Tags: javascript, typeof

This is really tearing apart my JS concept. What's wrong at all here?

```
const NAME = 'chusss';
var name = 123;
console.log(typeof name); // string, wasnt it supposed to print number?
console.log(name); // 123
```

Comment: Possible to duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605892/whats-wrong-with-the-variable-name-in-js/49605960#49605960

Comment: `name` seems to be a reserved word in Javascript. `var test = 123` gives number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with the variable name in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605892/whats-wrong-with-the-variable-name-in-js)

Comment: Wrap it all inside an IIFE `(function () { ....  }());` and you will avoid the collision with `window.name`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `name` variable actually belongs to `window.name` which lets you set the name of the window.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

> The name of the window is used primarily for setting targets for
>   hyperlinks and forms.

Further down it's written:

> Don't set the value to something unstring since its get method will
>   call the toString method.

Thus you always get a string returned.

---

If you still want to use the `name` variable but dont want to have the collision with `window.name`, then wrap your code inside a *immediate invoked function expression (IIFE)* and benefit from the functional scope.

**Demo**

```js
(function() {
  var name = 123;
  console.log(typeof name);
  console.log(name);
})();
```

---

If you run this code in **node.js** you won't observe that behaviour as `name` is not a property of the `global` object and thus not defined in global scope.

Comment: Is it better to say, the variable belongs to the `DOM`. And node.js does — not — have that. Better than `global` object? Although it is `global` in a browser. And — not — owned by the `global` object in node.js.