# Unexpected typeof value for number variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was just randomly practicing JS code today and I put this line of code and ran the code.

```js
var name = 45;
console.log(typeof name);
```

It told me the type of variable name is a string. It's very strange but type of Name is String yet when I typed this:

```js
var age = 45;
console.log(typeof age);
```

But here type of variable age is Number.
Why am I observing this kind of inconsistency? is it some convention or something like this?

Comment: Have you considered that `name` is either a reserved word or identifier? http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: do JS assign Types on names of variables? like 'name' will be assigned String type no matter value is 45 which is a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the variable “name” doesn't work with a JS object
?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object)

Comment: no no. no duplicate declaration sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were running this in a browser, then I think it's because the default execution context is the window object. Basically, every global value you declare becomes a property of the window object, and vice versa: every property of the window object is available as a global variable (e.g `console`). Window objects have a `name` property by default, and redeclaring it as a variable doesn't affect that. Anyway, that's the closest I can get to an explanation.

Comment: thanks. there are 2 Variable names. 'name' and 'status' these 2 are String. No matter you assign numbers to them.

Comment: If you look up the window object on MDN you can get a complete list of its properties, which will be the names you can't/probably shouldn't use for global variables.