# What features are added to Javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript

Things like the DOM and the XMLHttpRequest object is not part of any Ecmascript specification, if I've understood it correctly.

I understand that the feature set vary between browser vendors and versions, but in general, what more Javascript features are available to us in a browser environment that are not part of any Ecmascript specification?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API maybe

Comment: APIs such as XHR, Fetch, the DOM, Notifications, are almost all standardized by WHATWG or the W3C.

Comment: https://caniuse.com will give you cross-browser stats for all JS features

Comment: @CertainPerformance. Just wow, that's extensive. Just clarified a whole lot to me.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object - just to clarify that you are asking for very long list (which is usually off-topic as "too broad")