# Javascript: function is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

Below I have the simplest code. In my `name` function its all good, it works but in the `User_age` function I get the following error:

> User_age is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

```
User_age();

function User_age()
{
    var age = promt("what is your age");
    var printAge = "your age is" + age;
    console.log(printAge);
}
```

```
name();

function name(){

    var username = prompt("what is your name");
    var greed = "hello" + username;
    console.log(greed);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfecly fine for me.

Comment: Worked, perfectly fine for me. https://jsbin.com/qasovepeze/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Have you tried to have the parentheses on the same line as the function?

Comment: [Don't use the name `name` for a global function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object)

Comment: (ok, sorry, it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate, I missed that the error is "*User_age is not a function.*")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a small issue in your first function you are typing promt not prompt

```js
 User_age();

function User_age()
{
var age = prompt("what is your age");
var printAge = "your age is" + age;
console.log(printAge);
}

name();

function name(){

var username = prompt("what is your name");
var greed = "hello" + username;
console.log(greed);
}
```

Comment: check my answer for not posting others answers