# Javascript addEventListener leads to incorrect result

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem as I try to addEvenrListener to the form to validate the user input. However, there is something wrong with the code as it keeps showing "All done" even when I left blank the input or the input contains number inside. Can you guys let me know me where is the problem? Furthermore, what is the difference between onsubmit and addEventListener? Is there any way simpler to do this? I just start learning JavaScript so I just want to build my knowledge step by step starting from the bottom. Thank you so much!

```js
var check=document.getElementById("check");
var name=document.getElementById("name");
var reg     = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
function ipt(){
    if(name.value !== ""){
        if(!reg.test(name.value)){
            alert("Number not allowed")
        }
        else{
        alert("All done");
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter your name");
    }
}
check.addEventListener("submit", ipt());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Check</title>
        <script src="./check.js"  defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="check" id="check">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Comment: `check.addEventListener("submit", ipt);` and move your var declarations inside your function

Comment: The code is more likely to have the problem about logic but I checked several times and could not figure out the problem

Comment: It works well now, thank you to @j08691

Comment: addEventListener need a reference to call a function, not to execute it immediately

Comment: But I don't understand why by just moving var outside the function and inside the function have a different. When var outside, the function keep showing "All done" but why not "Please enter your name" or "Number not allowed"? Thank you so much

Comment: @BeefNoodle Because otherwise you are using the wrong `name`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you invoke the function with parenthesis () at the event listener, invoke the function without parenthesis.

Try creating your "check" and "name" variables inside the function ipt(), so immediately you submit the form, it will take the info that you previously typed in the input.

Creating your variables outside the function, the result will be undefined for the input value because js creates them as soon as the page is created and when you submit, those variables were already created at the beginning without any info.

here some official docs from MDN about submit eventListener.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Add your script at the bottom of the body, it gives the HTML the time to load before de Javascript code is executed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check</title>
</head>    
<body>
    <form name="check" id="check">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script src="./check.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here your Js file, add the event as an argument to your "ipt" function.

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

function ipt(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var check = document.getElementById("check");
    var name = document.getElementById("name");

    if (name.value !== "") {
        if (!reg.test(name.value)) {
            alert("Number not allowed")
        }
        else {
            alert("All done");
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter your name");
    }
}
check.addEventListener('submit', ipt);
```

Hope it works for You. Regards!