# can i print session storage directly in my browser console if i have already saved that?

Tags: javascript

for some reason i get 'The declaration was marked as deprecated here', any knows why is that so?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my variable show it's deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379554/why-does-my-variable-show-its-deprecated)