# why is part of the code for receiving message not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

I have given the client side and server side code for a real time chat application. Whenever I am sending a message, it is not being received by the other party. Also , in client.js,
`socket.emit("new-user-joined", name);`  , in this line, name is shown deprecated. As a result, the feature of giving notification when a person joins is not appearing in the app. Please suggest the solution.

**client.js:-**

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:8000");

// Get DOM elements in respective Js variables
const form = document.getElementById("send-container");
const messageInput = document.getElementById("messageInp");
const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".container");

// Audio that will play on receiving messages
var audio = new Audio("sound.mp3");


// Function which will append event info to the contaner
const append = (message, position) => {
  const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
  messageElement.innerText = message;
  messageElement.classList.add("message");
  messageElement.classList.add(position);
  messageContainer.append(messageElement);
  if (position == "left") {
    audio.play();
  }
};

// Ask new user for his/her name and let the server know
const name = prompt("Enter your name to join");
socket.emit("new-user-joined", name);

// If a new user joins, receive his/her name from the server
socket.on("user-joined", (name) => {
  append(`${name} joined the chat`, "right");
});

// If server sends a message, receive it
socket.on("receive", (data) => {
  append(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`, "left");
});

// If a user leaves the chat, append the info to the container
socket.on("left", (name) => {
  append(`${name} left the chat`, "right");
});

// If the form gets submitted, send server the message
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const message = messageInput.value;
  append(`You: ${message}`, "right");
  socket.emit("send", message);
  messageInput.value = "";
});
```

**server.js:-**

```
const io = require("socket.io")(8000);

const users = {};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // If any new user joins, let other users connected to the server know!
  socket.on("new-user-joined", (name) => {
    users[socket.id] = name;
    socket.broadcast.emit("user-joined", name);
  });

  // If someone sends a message, broadcast it to other people
  socket.on("send", (message) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("receive", {
      message: message,
      name: users[socket.id],
    });
  });

  // If someone leaves the chat, let others know
  socket.on("disconnect", (message) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("left", users[socket.id]);
    delete users[socket.id];
  });
});
```

Comment: This is [the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65379845/14469685) why "name" is deprecated - you should rename the `name` variable to `username` or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I am sending a message, it is not being received by the other party.what is wrong with the code??
why is it not working??

```
<script defer src=" http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js ">
</script> <script defer src="js/client.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).