# Why is the variable deprecated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below shows the name is deprecated, with the message:

```
'name' is deprecated.ts(6385) lib.dom.d.ts(17693, 5):
```

The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

```
let name = 'mayk';
let names = ['joao','felipe','marcelo'];
for(let char of name){
}
```

But if I set name1 for example it works,why is that?

Comment: name has another meaning in js. 
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379554/why-does-my-variable-show-its-deprecated

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy  flag it as duplicate if you find an answer elsewhere

Comment: Put your code inside a function. Then call your function. That should fix your issue...