# Typescript: destructuring type error when setting response

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having an issue with destructuring and types.  I have a custom type and a function that returns that type:

```
 interface CustomNameInfo {
     name: string;
     access: string
 }
```

---

```
 async getNameInfo(): Promise<CustomNameInfo> {
    //logic

    return {
       name: "FOO",
       access: "none"
    }
 }
```

---

if I use approach 1, I get no type errors:

```
 let name, access, resp;         

 if (!hasName) {
    resp = await this.getNameInfo();
    access = resp.access;
    name = resp.name;
 }
```

---

If I use the approach I am trying to use though with destructuring, I am getting the TS error: `Property 'access' and` name`does not exist on type`CustomNameInfo``

```
 let name, access;         

 if (!hasName) {
    ({ name, access } = await this.getNameInfo()); 
 }
```

Comment: Why is getNameInfo await when there is no async?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what you are doing wrong, but this [Stackblitz example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAOTjwgEkQYdkBvAWAChlkRiIA1OKALmWylADmAbgZNESTJh59BDAL4MGcTAE8QCZDHTqwwHCGQCIYIiXKUAFAEoeABSj5gmCAB4M2fKbIUcAPhqiyFDG6FAGdIxMzKwc3MgARABiAPLJ8QA0gWIIElIJIPoQ8YEK9KUMADbG0SSxPHAgKunI4hCS9Y0i9Eqq6praCLr6mjg41gGRwDDIFmBQ6BBWE1Ez1DXsnM2tkshyyAC8LQDucMBghsZe5mNWVl1MpUwI%20pg4VQB0FTgCFiy1my0cm1MMgrPIGJQbkIgA) works as expected:

```js
interface CustomNameInfo {
  nameVar: string;
  access: string
}

async function getNameInfo(): Promise<CustomNameInfo> {
  return {
    nameVar: "FOO",
    access: "none"
  }
}

let nameVar: any, access: any;

async function foo() {
  if (true) {
    ({ nameVar, access } = await getNameInfo());
  }
  console.log(nameVar, access )
}
foo();
```

BTW: don't use `name` as top-levle variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65379845/1041641