# how to implement addItem using react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've implemented user list and can delete users dispatching action deleteUser().
Now I add user but once I click add button the data is not mapped in the list.
this is a reducer:

```
case ADD_USERS:
          const newId = state.users[state.users.length-1] + 1
          return {
              ...state,
              users: [
                ...state.users,
                {
                  id: newId,
                  name: action.payload
                }
              ],
              loading: false
  
          }
```

initial state consists of 2 objects and loading key.
The action function is simple:

```
export function addUser (name) {
  return {
    type: ADD_USERS,
    payload: name
  }
```

and the component is there:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ users: state.users });
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    deleteUser: id => {
      dispatch(deleteUser(id))
    },
    addUser: name => {
      dispatch(addUsers(name))
    }
  }
     
};


const Users = (props) => {
  const { users } = props.users;


  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <input type='text' placeholder='name..'/>
    <button onClick={() => props.addUser(name)}>add</button>
      <h2>Users</h2>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-1">
            <li>{user.name}</li>
            <button onClick={() => props.deleteUser(user.id)}>x</button>
           
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
}
```

I consider getUsers don't work or I can be wrong. cause I map state to props and display the data inside

{user.name}

I think it should work same with getUsers()

Comment: *Typo:* Seems like you have incorrect mapping: `addUser: name => { dispatch(deleteUser(name)) }`. It should be mapped with, e.g, `addUser(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the only one issue, but at least this looks strange to me:

```
const { users } = props.users;
```

Because, with the line above you are creating a constant with value from `props.users.users`. You have not shown how you use the `Users` component and what it gets from outside, but this looks at least strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => props.addUser(name)}>add</button>
```

Your `button` calls `addUser` with a variable `name`, **but that variable doesn't exist!**

You need to change your `input` into a controlled component so that you can call `addUser` with the name from the `input` field.

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");

return (
  <>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="name.."
      value={name}
      onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
    />
    <button onClick={() => props.addUser(name)}>add</button>
...
```

Comment: This may be possible because `name` is a [global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/2873538) variable, and they might not get error or warning.

Comment: @AjeetShah interesting!