# How do I pass a Javascript variable into JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I'm a coding novice, trying to learn! I have passed a query parameter into a JavaScript variable using the below:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString);
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var name = urlParams.get('id')
```

And would now like to pass it into JSON, within the below div

```
<div 
 class="review-form" 
 data-site-uuid="xxxxxx" 
 data-form-uuid="xxxxxx" 
 data-prefill='{"firstName":name}'
></div>
```

Such that my parameter will ultimately populate on the review form.

Any help much appreciated!

I initially tried passing the JavaScript variable into the field before realising it was JSON.

Comment: Warning: You haven't shown where your JavaScript code above is, but **if** it's at global scope, it's important to use `let name = ___` instead of `var name = ___` because the latter will try to set the window's `name` property. (Or use a name other than `name`. Or better yet, don't put your code at global scope, use [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).) More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the target `div` already exists in the page by the time your JavaScript code runs, and it is uniquely-identifiable via an `id` or a CSS selector. If so:

1. Locate the element (via [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) if you're using an `id`, via [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) if not).
2. Create the JSON by creating an object with `name` as its `firstName` property, then using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get the JSON for that object:  `JSON.stringify({firstName: name})`.
3. Set the `data-prefix` attribute via [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

For example, **if** this is the only element with the class `review-form` (or the first one):

```
const element = document.querySelector(".review-form");
const json = JSON.stringify({firstName: name});
element.setAttribute("data-prefix", json);
```

You could also use the [`element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) object instead of the `element.setAttribute` method, but for a beginner, I'd stick with the simple `setAttribute` for now.